# SSL protocol error on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, ssl

I was trying to open google on my windows 10 system via smartphone when both firefox and chrome threw SSL protocol errors.  Chrome throws "SSL Protocol error" and Firefox throws a more severe "SSL_ERROR_RX_UNEXPECTED_APPLICATION_DATA". Even the internet explorer is not working. Note that torrent engine is working correctly BTW which means it is more of a browser error. I have tried almost every trivial method on the internet regarding SSL errors as well. Now, a few other sites are working when explicitly told not to worry about the SSL issue, but not google and facebook.

I used hotspot earlier but then resorted to usb tethering, all to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean "via smartphone"?

Comment: Do you mean you're connected to the internet via a hotspot on your mobile phone?

Comment: I am using the hotspot from my android phone on the laptop.